# Layouts/Views in Towerjs

Tags: node.js, towerjs

i have a quick question regarding views/layouts.

I have installed & setup a working tower bot, however whenever i call: `@render 'viewName'` from within a controller, (this includes the example controller generated by running `tower new appName`) the clients template.js file is generated, but its contents is never inserted into the layout.

From what I can see in the layout, it would make sense for the view to replace the handlebar token `{{outlet}}` However, I cannot see any reason why it should.

I have scoured the documentation, but as it is still being written it seems to be lacking any instruction that can help me.

I'm sure its something simple I am missing.

Any help is appreciated. Relevant code below. (All code from default install)

Thanks in advance.

---

app/controllers/server/applicationController.coffee:

```
class App.ApplicationController extends Tower.Controller
  @layout 'application'

  ...

  welcome: ->
    @render 'welcome', locals: {@bootstrapData}

  ...
```

app/templates/shared/layout/_body.coffee_body.coffee:

```
...
section id: 'content', role: 'main', ->
  div class: 'container', ->
    text '{{outlet}}\n'
...
```

app/templates/shared/welcome.coffee:

```
h1 'Welcome to Tower.js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the towerjs source code I have discovered that the `@render` function assigns the view to the name 'body', so inserting that view is as easy as:

app/templates/shared/layout/_body.coffee_body.coffee:

```
...
section id: 'content', role: 'main', ->
  div class: 'container', ->
    yields 'body'
...
```

I hope this helps someone else.